# call an apex method from javascript

Tags: apex, visualforce, json

I have an apex method that returns a result in this form `Map<String, List<Map<String,String>>>`
And I'd like to use this result localy to generate two dependent picklist. 
How can I call this method from my javascript code ? 
I haven't created the JS function yet.. Can someone tell me how to proceed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using VF page then you can call it using action:function.

Apex method:

```
    public PageReference getMyMethod(){
    ....
    return null;
}
```

Visualforce page action function:

```
<apex:actionFunction action="{!MyMethod}" name="myFunction" />
```

actionFunction works like a javascript function, so you can call it from anywhere at your page like this:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!something}" onchange="myFunction()" />
```

and if you want call it from JavaScript button pls see this link

http://blog.shivanathd.com/2014/07/call-apex-class-from-custom-button-salesforce.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer i understand now how to do the call.. 
In my JS function how can I put the result of my apex method in a variable ? Is it possible to do something like var res = myApexMethod(); ?

Comment: I have tried that and I get res = false ? i don't understand why..

Comment: You can not assign the value like this. If you want to display it on VF page then you need to create getter method. which would be something like this -- getMyMethod, get keyword with your method name, so here myMethod will hold value and you can use on the page.

Comment: Can you explain more please ? should I create a getter method that returns a pageReference ?